# How to get all children of a model through another model that has a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a multi-level category model with the columns `id, name, category_id`

I then have a `Product` model, which has many `SubProduct` models.

The `Category` and `Product` Models have a many-to-many relationship with a junction table.

I am confused on how i can get all the SubProducts of a Category.

If i do this: `$category->products[0]->childProducts;` I am able to get all the child products, however i want a way to do this without indexing the products and to get all the categories products.

The code for my models is below:

**Category.php** (note i made a subProducts function with hasManyThrough but maybe its incorrect usage?)

```
class Category extends Model
{
    // Get the sub categories for the category.
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    // Get the parent category that owns the category.
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }


    // Get the products
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function subProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(SkuProduct::class, Product::class);
    }

}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function childProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubProduct::class, 'product_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the category that owns the product.
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**SubProduct.php**

```
class SubProduct extends Mode
{

    public function parentProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(SubProduct::class, Product::class, 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: yes i tried that but i get: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.category_id' in 'field list' That is because category_id is in the Category model. There is a many to many relation between category and products.

Comment: sorry, I was confused because your Product class has a category method which is belongsTo()

Comment: I think you might have to use another pivot table for Category - SubProduct and have another belongsToMany(SubProduct::class).